Is there a way to refresh the DI object only (Blazor Server)
I have an issue with Blazor Server:
my DI always get the same ID (instance) on the component's button click

For example:
ILoginService.ID = "123"
When i click a button - if the login fails , and retry it will have the same instance ID ="123"
The dependency injection was defined below:

I am aware that if I refresh the page, the DI will work as expected (because it is scope service - new every request) . but it's not fit on my scenario.
I have to refresh the DI object only before or after the button click, so i have a new instance each button click
Is there a way to refresh the DI object only
Already changed the lifetime of DI to transient. Still not working

I was expecting the following
Before Click:
ILoginService.ID = "123"
Then Login failed
Retry Click
ILoginService.ID = "456"

How do you set the ID in your LoginService? If this would be a static field, then thats the reason for the ID to be the same.

@decius it's not static, it's dynamically assigned. NewGuid .
It's the same id each login request (retry), the instance doesn't change as i check the id

Could you share the code of this part of the LoginService?

Your service consists of a set of methods and some state objects.  Split out the state into a separate object and renew that.  Does the service inject other services?

In Blazor Server, components may reuse the same instance of the component upon button clicks, which can affect the retrieval and management of service instances. Even if the service is transient, a new service instance might not be created due to component caching mechanisms.
So, to ensure that a new LoginService instance is obtained with each button click, you can create a new scope by using IServiceScopeFactory.
Below is my test demo:
LoginService:
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    public string ID { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    // ...
}

Login.razor:
@page "/login"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IServiceScopeFactory ScopeFactory

<h3>Test</h3>

<button @onclick="HandleLogin">Login</button>
<p> ID: @id</p>

@code {
    private string id;

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        using (var scope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var loginService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoginService>();
            id = loginService.ID;
        }
    }
}

Also register the service as:
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();

My test results:
First click:

Second click:


Great. This works..
